# Start Fluid simulation before frame 0

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want an object to emerge from the water. So I've created a domain and a water object in order to create my water.

When I begin the simulation it needs several frames for the water to settle down into the domain (edit: I could have simply made the *Flow* object a bit bigger than the *Domain* but anyway...), so I thought I should begin the calculation at frame -50 for example (*Cache > Frame Start*), so that the water has already settled down when the animation begins, but it doesn't change anything (!?!), the animation is exactly the same and it still takes several frames for the water to settle down.

What am I missing? Thanks. File [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/af1a675407214a678319a4b50b9faa2e).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Offset* value you can enter in the *Cache* settings is just usable if you're loading a saved simulation cache and doesn't work for baking. Baking can only be calculated between **positive** *Start* and *End* frames. Before I simply retype everything that's in the manual, here is a screenshot:

[image: cache offset]

Comment: ooh ok thanks  ;)  I'll put your answer as accepted

Comment: a bit tedious for the collision object animation though as you need to offset it then bring it back

Comment: Sure, but I'm afraid I can't change that :D

Comment: come on Gordon, please...  ^^

Comment: NO! (evil laughter) :D sorry for being off-topic

Comment: actually it looks like if the Flow is a bigger than the Domain it works as well, so I don't have to wait for the water to settle down

Comment: I'm sorry, actually that's what I usually do - I didn't think of pointing that out because I was too focused on the offset topic.

Comment: no problem, it was useful to know anyway